# Truncating a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know this is absurd but I am stuck at it

I have a filepath using fileupload in asp classic

The filepath is *C:\FakePath\3.jpg*

I want to retrieve it in a variable so that it would only give me *3.jpg*

`substring()` and `substr()` doesn't include 3 I don't know why

```
logopath = C:\FakePath\3.jpg;
logopath = logopath.substring(10);
```

Comment: Please post they way you use the `substring()` or `substr()`

Comment: If you want it only with JavaScript please don't use other tags.

Answer (score 2):

try this

`'C:\\FakePath\\3.jpg'.split('\\').pop();` // "3.jpg"

or (regex)

```
'C:\\FakePath\\3.jpg'.replace(/^.*\\/, '');   // "3.jpg"
```

[image]

Comment: there is only single slash

Comment: there is only a single slash in your _display string_. how would you know if `\t` is `backslash t` or `tab` ? in js you should use `special chars`.

Comment: it will always be a backslash not tab ever

Comment: Perhaps, play with js and you'll know what @RoyiNamir is talking about. (http://jsfiddle.net/g3cUK/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to use substring:

```
var str="C:\\FakePath\\3.jpg";
var imgName = str.substring(12);
```

Comment: Note that the string would need ``\\``. Also, `12` is needed to strip the last ``\`` as well.

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb I realized it after a while.

Comment: but there is no \\ only single \

Comment: Backslash has a special meaning. Although it is w3Schools, but still : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
logopath = encodeURIComponent( logopath ).replace( /.+FakePath%0/, '' )
```

'\3' is being interpreted as an octal escape sequence which points to a non-printable ASCII character.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to solve it  **in classic ASP,** plesae try this.

```
<%
dim aryPath
aryPath = Split("C:\FakePath\3.jpg","\")
Response.Write aryPath(2)
%>
```

Hope it could be helpful.

Comment: OP asks for JavaScript; note that you can write server-side Classic ASP in either JavaScript or VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use such code:

```
function FileChanged(input) {
    var fullPath = input.value;
    var index = fullPath.lastIndexOf("\\");
    var fileName = (index < 0) ? fullPath : fullPath.substr(index + 1);
    alert(fileName);
}​
```

The two middle lines are what you need: they will take the value after the last slash. This way it doesn't matter what is the path, it will always return only the file name.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/U2pVT/).